# Flutter: How wo multiple select answers in a quiz

Tags: flutter, multiple-select

I'm new to Flutter/Dart and trying to develop a quiz app. In the quiz there‘ll be questions where you have to choose one answer or sometimes more than one. Unfortunately I can't find a solution. I've already thought about implementing a "ChoiceChip", but the answers aren’t displayed as I want.
I want the answers to display like this, but with the option to select more than one answer.

[flutter quiz app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74my0.png)

Does anyone happen to have an idea how I could implement this?

Comment: Have you started anything that you'd like to share with us (code snippet) so we can provide guidance, or you're starting from scratch?

Comment: I‘m starting from scratch. I had a List of questions and answers, but it seemed like that wouldn‘t work, so I delete it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the answers are laid out in ListView, for each answer clicked, add it to an answersList, that holds all of the answers for that particular question.

Or you can refer this package [multi_select_flutter 4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter/install)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! This might work actually, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag while adding a question that the question has multiple pick answers or not if that is the scenario you can use a comma separate string in it.